# MUI default dashboard template, localStorage bug

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, local-storage

I'm developing nextjs app. For a start I downloaded this default dashboard theme from MUI website https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/templates/dashboard/ code: https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.10.13/docs/data/material/getting-started/templates/dashboard/Dashboard.tsx
However, when I try to implement localStorage that will store "open" drawer state like in the snippet bellow it bugs- on refresh it's always in the default state, even if the value in localStorage is set to false (when trying to log the stored value, it is correct). When I try to click the button after the refresh with false value nothing happens because it sets the value to true, only next click takes an effect. Any idea what may cause that bug? According to error: `Warning: Prop className did not match. Server: "MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorInherit MuiIconButton-edgeStart MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-1johsky-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root" Client: "MuiButtonBase-root MuiIconButton-root MuiIconButton-colorInherit MuiIconButton-edgeStart MuiIconButton-sizeMedium css-dhvns5-MuiButtonBase-root-MuiIconButton-root"`

My code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@mui/material/CssBaseline';
import MuiDrawer from '@mui/material/Drawer';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import MuiAppBar, { AppBarProps as MuiAppBarProps } from '@mui/material/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@mui/material/Toolbar';
import List from '@mui/material/List';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Divider from '@mui/material/Divider';
import IconButton from '@mui/material/IconButton';
import Badge from '@mui/material/Badge';
import Container from '@mui/material/Container';
import Grid from '@mui/material/Grid';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Link from '@mui/material/Link';
import MenuIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@mui/icons-material/ChevronLeft';
import NotificationsIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Notifications';
import theme from "../theme";
import { firstListMenu, secondaryListMenu } from './MenuList';
import {useEffect, useState} from "react";


const drawerWidth: number = 200;

interface AppBarProps extends MuiAppBarProps {
    open?: boolean;
}

type Props = {
    children?: JSX.Element;
}

const AppBar = styled(MuiAppBar, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open',
})<AppBarProps>(({ theme, open }) => ({
    zIndex: theme.zIndex.drawer + 1,
    transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
        easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
    }),
    ...(open && {
        marginLeft: drawerWidth,
        width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`,
        transition: theme.transitions.create(['width', 'margin'], {
            easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
            duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
        }),
    }),
}));

const Drawer = styled(MuiDrawer, { shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'open' })(
    ({ theme, open }) => ({
        '& .MuiDrawer-paper': {
            position: 'relative',
            whiteSpace: 'nowrap',
            width: drawerWidth,
            transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
                easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                duration: theme.transitions.duration.enteringScreen,
            }),
            boxSizing: 'border-box',
            ...(!open && {
                overflowX: 'hidden',
                transition: theme.transitions.create('width', {
                    easing: theme.transitions.easing.sharp,
                    duration: theme.transitions.duration.leavingScreen,
                }),
                width: theme.spacing(7),
                [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
                    width: theme.spacing(9),
                },
            }),
        },
    }),
);

const mdTheme = theme;

export default function Layout({children}: Props) {
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(() => {
        try {
            const value = window.localStorage.getItem('open');

            if (value) {
                return JSON.parse(value);
            } else {
                window.localStorage.setItem('open', JSON.stringify(true));
                return true;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return true;
        }
    });

    const toggleDrawer = () => {
        try {
            window.localStorage.setItem('open', JSON.stringify(!open));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        setOpen(!open);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(open)
    })

    return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={mdTheme}>
            <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                <CssBaseline />
                <AppBar position="absolute" open={open}>
                    <Toolbar
                        sx={{
                            pr: '24px', // keep right padding when drawer closed
                        }}
                    >
                        <IconButton
                            edge="start"
                            color="inherit"
                            aria-label="open drawer"
                            onClick={toggleDrawer}
                            sx={{
                                marginRight: '36px',
                                ...(open && { display: 'none' }),
                            }}
                        >
                            <MenuIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                        <Typography
                            component="h1"
                            variant="h6"
                            color="inherit"
                            noWrap
                            sx={{ flexGrow: 1 }}
                        >
                            Dashboard
                        </Typography>
                        <IconButton color="inherit">
                            <Badge badgeContent={4} color="secondary">
                                <NotificationsIcon />
                            </Badge>
                        </IconButton>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
                <Drawer variant="permanent" open={open}>
                    <Toolbar
                        sx={{
                            display: 'flex',
                            alignItems: 'center',
                            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
                            px: [1],
                        }}
                    >
                        <IconButton onClick={toggleDrawer}>
                            <ChevronLeftIcon />
                        </IconButton>
                    </Toolbar>
                    <Divider />
                    <List component="nav">
                        {firstListMenu}
                        <Divider sx={{ my: 1 }} />
                        {secondaryListMenu}
                    </List>
                </Drawer>
                <Box
                    component="main"
                    sx={{
                        backgroundColor: (theme) =>
                            theme.palette.mode === 'light'
                                ? theme.palette.grey[100]
                                : theme.palette.grey[900],
                        flexGrow: 1,
                        height: '100vh',
                        overflow: 'auto',
                    }}
                >
                    <Toolbar />
                    <Container maxWidth="lg" sx={{ mt: 4, mb: 4 }}>

                        <Grid container spacing={3}>
                            {/* Chart */}
                            <Grid item xs={12} md={8} lg={9}>
                                <Paper
                                    sx={{
                                        p: 2,
                                        display: 'flex',
                                        flexDirection: 'column',
                                        height: 240,
                                    }}
                                >
                                    {children}
                                </Paper>
                            </Grid>
                            {/* Recent Deposits */}
                            <Grid item xs={12} md={4} lg={3}>
                                <Paper
                                    sx={{
                                        p: 2,
                                        display: 'flex',
                                        flexDirection: 'column',
                                        height: 240,
                                    }}
                                >
                                </Paper>
                            </Grid>
                            {/* Recent Orders */}
                            <Grid item xs={12}>
                                <Paper sx={{ p: 2, display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                                </Paper>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </Container>
                </Box>
            </Box>
        </ThemeProvider>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem occured because it is rendered on server side. I had to change localStorage to cookies and use getServerSideProps.